# JS-created dropdown with bootstrap/HTML is not being recognised by an onchange trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

Have tied myself in some knots here - so would welcome any thoughts on how to untie them. Am using js and bootstrap to create a specifically formatted dropdown. This function is called on an if statement and works successfully:

```
      function updateMFin2() {
      document.getElementById('containermFin2').innerHTML = '';

      var values = arrmPlayer.slice(4, 8); //Just an array with 4 string elements in it

      var m_fin2List = values.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r + '</option>\n'; }).join('');

      var divx2 = document.createElement("m_fin2");
      divx2.innerHTML =
          '<div class="input-group">\n' +
          '<label class="input-group-text">F2</label>\n' +
          '<select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="m_fin2">\n' +
          "<option selected>Men's Finalist #2</option>\n" +
          m_fin2List +
          '</select>\n' +
          '<input class="input-group-text" disabled id="drawfin2" class="validate" type="text"  style="width:60px;" value="-" aria-label="readonly input example" readonly>\n' +       
          '</div>\n';

      document.getElementById("containermFin2").appendChild(divx2); 
      }
```

Then using an onchange for m_fin2 I want to call another function which does something e.g.

```
   document.getElementById("m_fin2").addEventListener("change",getmFBH);

   function getmFBH(evt){
    //do something
   }
```

The good news is that this is working insofar as the dropdowns are being created dynamically from the user-determined 'values' - however (possibly because of the way I am scripting the dropdowns in the div container?) the onchange doesn't work.

Have tried various approaches, including trying to shrink down the amount of HTML included in the divx2.innerHTML (would like this to be as little as possible and just focus on the 'option' list - however I couldn't get that to work either). Advice gratefully received on solving the problem or recommending the best practice way to do this and still have the bootstrap formatting work.

Comment: Well you remove the element and recreate it with innerHTML. Where are you attaching the event after you create it again? That event does not keep getting bound to elements with the same id.

Comment: Great point - I have now included the event onchange attach in the function and it works fine. Thanks!